# How to query filtering by a ByteString field in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have

```
class Map(db.Model):
    urlHash= db.ByteStringProperty()

hasher = hashlib.sha256()
hasher.update(staticMapUrl)
urlHash = hasher.digest()
query = db.Query(models.Map)
query = query.filter('urlHash =', urlHash)
results = query.fetch(1)
```

and this type of query tries to decode the `urlHash` to a string, throwing an exception

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xfe in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Pls show the code that sets urlHash for the query.

Comment: @cope360 I added the code to the question body

Comment: Can you include the complete stacktrace of the exception, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it will work if you explicitly make the hash into a `ByteString`:

```
from google.appengine.api.datastore_types import ByteString

hasher = hashlib.sha256()
hasher.update('http://www.google.com/')
urlHash = hasher.digest()
bs = ByteString(urlHash)

m = Map(urlHash=bs).put()

query = db.Query(Map)
query = query.filter('urlHash =', bs)
results = query.fetch(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution I found is to encode manually to base64

```
urlHash = hasher.digest().encode('base64')
```

I noted that besides the name of the exception being `UnicodeDecodeError`, it occurs on encoding too.